# Starting screen without welcome screen

Tags: gnu-screen

Running `screen` I see this:

> [image]

How can I start screen directly, without this welcome screen?

Comment: You can also switch to `tmux` which does not have startup screen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `startup_message off` to your .screenrc:

```
startup_message on|off
```

> Select whether you want to see the  copyright  notice  during  startup.
>       Default is `on', as you probably noticed.

Actually, the default is to display the startup message only when screen is not passed any argument.

Comment: I didn't had the file, but I created it `nano ~/.screenrc` and pasted `startup_message off` in it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This can be updated globally in /etc/screenrc

Answer (score 2):

You also don't get it if you start `screen` with the name of a screen session.

```
$ screen -S newsession
```

You can then reconnect to it later on:

```
$ screen -r newsession
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsing through the man-page of `screen`, I encountered

> -f, -fn, and -fa
>
> ```
>        turns flow-control on, off, or "automatic switching mode".  This can also be defined through the "defflow" .screenrc command.
> ```

And indeed, with `screen -f` I do not get this kind of splash-screen. Please check with [this Flow Control Summary](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Flow-Control-Summary.html) if it somehow interferes with your work, as I do not have experience with this settings.